# Jquery variable not defined error

Tags: jquery, variables

I use the following jquery statements but i get error in this

```
function onGetDataSuccess(result) {
Iteratejsondata(result);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pager").pager({ pagenumber: 1, pagecount: 5, buttonClickCallback: PageClick });
});

PageClick = function(pageclickednumber) {
    $("#pager").pager({ pagenumber: pageclickednumber, pagecount: 15, buttonClickCallback: PageClick });
    $("#ResultsDiv").html("Clicked Page " + pageclickednumber);
         }
    }         
}
```

**Error:**`PageClick` is not defined....

Comment: You didn't assign any value to the `PageClick` hence the undefined message..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the way you create the PageClick function it could be parsed after the other code or the PageClick variable is not in scope.

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var PageClick = function(pageclickednumber) {
            $("#pager").pager({ pagenumber: pageclickednumber, pagecount: 15, buttonClickCallback: PageClick });
            $("#ResultsDiv").html("Clicked Page " + pageclickednumber);
        }

        $("#pager").pager({ pagenumber: 1, pagecount: 5, buttonClickCallback: PageClick });
    });
```